# Intellisense não funciona

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, intellisense

Estou a utilizar o visual studio 2010 e do nada o intellisense deixou de funcionar.
Já desliguei e voltei a ligar o computador, reiniciei as definições do visual studio, já fiz **Ctrl + Shift + Espaço** para ativar e nada resolve...
Alguém me poderá ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vá a:

**Tools** ► **Options** ► **Text Editor** ► **All Languages** ► **General**:

Selecione as colunas **Auto list numbers** e **Parameter Information**

Build a Solution e reinicie o visual studio

Comment: testei e não funcionou

Comment: Estavam desativadas? Se sim, experimente reiniciar o Visual Studio!

Comment: Não estavam ativadas! Desativei, voltei a ativar, reiniciei o Visual Studio e não deu!

Comment: Build a solution e reinicie outra vez!

Comment: obrigado já resolveu

Comment: agora funciona num projeto, mas noutro nao...

Comment: Estava com o projeto aberto? ou quando abriu outro aconteceu o mesmo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76599/discussion-between-jose-gomes-and-idkwhy).